# How to get numbers by using regular expression, but only last one

Tags: shell-script, regular-expression

In this example I can get `00`.

```
expr match "00 foo 99.jpg" '[^0-9]*\([0-9]\+\).*$'
```

I want to know how to get last number from string, in this case `99` by using regular expression.

The string may contain only a set of numbers like "foo00.jpg", or several of them like "00 foo 11 bar 22 foo.jpg".

How can I write the regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file="00 foo 99.jpg"
expr "x$file" : '.*[^0-9]\([0-9]\{1,\}\)'
```

Don't use `echo` for arbitrary data, you can't use `sed` as `sed` works on lines and filenames can be made of several lines.

`match` is not a standard operator of `expr`, `:` is the standard equivalent, so you might as well use it instead to avoid portability issues.

Prefixing `$file` with `x` makes sure `$file` is not taken as an `expr` operator. (and in this case helps in cases where the numbers are not preceded by non-numbers).

Note that the above has an unwanted side-effect that it returns a non-zero exit status if the returned number is 0 (or `00`, `000`...).

`\+` is not a standard basic regexp operator. `\{1,\}` is the standard equivalent (though you could also write it `[0-9][0-9]*`).

You don't need to use `expr` here, you could also use the shell (any POSIX shell) parameter expansion:

```
file="00 foo 99.jpg"
number=x${file}x
number=${number%[!0-9]*}
number=${number##*[!0-9]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU sed's extended regex syntax (BSD `sed`s have `-E` instead of `-r`):

```
$ echo  "00 foo 99.jpg" | sed -r  's/(^|.*[^0-9])([0-9]+)[^0-9]*$/\2/' 
99
```

Using GNU `expr match` instead of `sed`:

```
$ expr match "$(echo "01 foo 89.jpg" | rev)" '[^0-9]*\([0-9]\+\)' | rev
89
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `grep`:

```
$ echo "00 foo 99.jpg" | grep -o '[[:digit:]]\+' | tail -n1
99
```